# "Unable to locate adb" popping up in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am using Android Studio 4.1.2 in Windows 10 Education 64-bit for Flutter Development. Whenever I try to run the virtual device emulator, a pop up appears "Unable to locate adb". What can I do to remove/solve this pop-up?

Comment: This is not a flutter specific error, just search for "unable to locate adb" and there are many solutions. Simply put, you haven't installed it fully: there is one step you now need to, which is edit the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I have edited the PATH environment variable as per the instruction given in the flutter.dev [https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows] but didn't work.

Comment: The flutter guide does not show how to do what I mean (edit the environment variable for android studio). More specifically, you need to add the `android-studio/bin` path (You'll need to replace `android-studio` with the location of it. In my case, the path is `/opt/android-studio/bin`, but in your case, it will be something like `"C:\Program Files\android-studio\bin"`. But make sure it exists first (navigate to it using Windows Explorer, then copy the path).

Comment: Also read the first link I shared, there are many things you can try.